# Bias in P-value of MM-type estimators or Cochrans Q Penalized Regression

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, inference, linear, selectiveinference

There are a number of linear regression methods designed to limit the influence of outliers on estimates:

- For example, Cochrans Q Penalised regression as described in [1] will do an initial linear regression, then downweighting data points which are outlying from this initial regression.
- Or, MM-type estimators will run the regression twice calculating the residual of datapoints to the regression line then subsequently eliminating outliers. Running this procedure *twice*.

**Is it true that:**
Given, this two step procedure, the P-values derived from these estimates are biased since the model is observing the data twice.

One could repeatedly run an MM-type estimator and progressively constrain to find a significant regression line in **any** dataset purely by repeated exclusion of 'outlying' datapoints.

[1] https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6756542/

Answer (score 1):

1. Penalized regression does *not* do an initial regression and then downweight points "outlying" from this initial regression. $L_1$ and $L_2$-penalized regressions do not weight observations at all (de facto). In fact, $L_1$-penalized regression (LASSO) is *more* prone to bias d/t outlier because it tends to select regressors based on large coefficient values. The same is not true of ridge which tends to attenuate effects ($L_2$ penalty).
2. The ordinary least squares regression coefficient *is* a method of moment estimator. $$ \mathbf{X}^T (Y - \mathbf{X}^T\beta) = 0$$ gives rise to the OLS parameters. Although the method is so broad, some of the specialized outlier-robust methods may have estimating equation formulations as well. By virtue of being a root finding algorithm, it does *not* "run" twice, but a solution can be obtained using Newton-Raphson or a similar approach.
3. Data are never observed "twice" even in iterative estimation routines. Data are observed once by virtue of their being data.
4. Automated or manual outlier deletion leads to biased and inefficient estimates.
5. If data are wrong they should be deleted or, better, fixed regardless of whether they are outliers.
6. The only routine which comes close to the two-step processes you are trying to describe would be a trimmed OLS where a proportion of the extreme residuals are excluded from analysis and the OLS is recalculated from the central subset.
7. A minimax approach to the regression routine that would "downweight" residuals would be to minimize the following objective function:
   $$ \beta = \text{arg min} \rho (Y-\mathbf{X} \beta$$
   where $\rho$ is a convex loss function. Choosing $\rho(r) = r^2$ gives OLS, but you can, say, choose $\rho(r) = r^2/(r^2+1)$ where the loss is locally quadratic near $r=0$ but converges to a constant 1 in the tails. 
   [image]

Comment: Hi, I was not referring to L1 or L2 penalization but different forms of penalized regression, see: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6756542/
Here you can also see the MM-estimation procedure described as: "Under this method, a S-estimate is fitted to minimize the M-estimate of scale, which has the desired high breakdown point but may lack efficiency. The estimates for the scale and regression parameters obtained in this stage are then used to fit an M-estimator with high efficiency, where the scale estimate is held constant to retain the high-breakdown point [20]."

Comment: updated answer to reflect the fact that I was not referring to L1 or L2 Penalization.